# Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK fails with initialization error while used in both main app and framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-dfp, native-ads, google-mobile-ads

I've an iOS app which has a framework in it. Framework is being used in main app. Both main app and framework need to use `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` for loading ads.
Here is podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyFramework' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.67.0'
  ...

end

target 'MainApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '~> 3.5.3'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.67.0'
  ...

end
```

This is how I'm requesting ads, from both main app and framework:

```
        let videoOptions = GADVideoOptions()
        var adOptions = [GADAdLoaderOptions]()
        adOptions.append(videoOptions)
        let adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: "ad id",
                               rootViewController: nil,
                               adTypes: adTypes,
                               options: adOptions)
        adLoader.delegate = self
        
        let dfpRequest = DFPRequest()
        dfpRequest.contentURL = "some url"
        
        adLoader.load(dfpRequest)
```

Main app is requesting ads before framework does.
This code works perfectly fine in framework but gives below error in main app:

> Domain=com.google.admob Code=2 "SDK tried to perform a networking task before being initialized." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=SDK tried to perform a networking task before being initialized.,
> gad_response_info=  ** Response Info **
> Response ID: (null)
> Network: (null)
> ** Mediation line items **

If I remove `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` from framework pods then main app works perfectly.

**What can be wrong in this?**

Somehow I feel like this is related to cocoapods but not sure... I have tried lots of ways by modifying podfile (but not worked) like:
Try-1

```
target 'MyFramework' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.67.0'

  target 'MainApp' do
    inherit! :complete
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '~> 3.5.3'
  end

end
```

Try-2

```
def ad_pods
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.67.0'
end

target 'MyFramework' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
  ad_pods
end

target 'MainApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '~> 3.5.3'
  ad_pods
end
```

and lot of other ways.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: have you found the solution? [2]